# ¿Cómo podría tener unas notas entre 0 y 7?

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles, while

necesito ingresar un numero n de asistentes de una capacitacion en la cual, a cada uno tengo que ingresarles una nota y posteriormente calcular el promedio de todas las notas ingresadas. Mi duda radica, en ¿Cómo puedo indicar que las notas ingresadas sean un dígito no mayor a 7?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cantidadAsistentes = 0;
    int suma = 0;
    int prom = 0; 
    

    while (cantidadAsistentes <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese Cantidad de asistentes: ");
        cantidadAsistentes = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();
    }
    
    String[] nombresAsistentes = new String[cantidadAsistentes];
    //Registro de los asistentes
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadAsistentes; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del asistente " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        nombresAsistentes[i] = entrada.nextLine();
    }
    
    int notas;
    
    notas = cantidadAsistentes;
    
    for(int n=1; n<= notas; n++){
        System.out.println("ingrese nota del asistente"+" "+n+" "+":");          
        int nota = entrada.nextInt();  
        suma = suma + nota;
    }
        prom= suma /notas;
        System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );
}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! con un if(nota < 7)??? cual seria la duda real???

Comment: Puedes volver a pedir la nota hasta que ingrese una válida

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int n = 1; n <= notas; n++ ) {
    System.out.println( "ingrese nota del asistente " + n + " :" );   
    boolean invalida = true;  
    while( invalida ) {     
        int nota = entrada.nextInt(); 
        if( nota <= 7 /* && 0 <= nota */ ) {
            invalida = false; 
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println( "por favor, ingrese una nota válida" );
        }
    }
    suma = suma + nota;
}
```

Con un simple agregado a tu código logramos el cometido.
La variable **invalida** es usada como condición para la ejecución del `while`, tomamos la nota ingresada, con el `if` verificamos que este en el rango correcto, si está, pasamos a **invalida** a `false`, por lo que salimos del bucle, si no está, mostramos un nuevo mensaje, y se repite el ciclo.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(int n=1; n<= notas; n++){
        int nota = -1;
        while (nota < 0 || nota > 7) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese nota del asistente " + n + " (un numero entre 0 y 7):");
            nota = entrada.nextInt();
            if (nota < 0 || nota > 7) {
                System.out.println("Nota invalida. Por favor, ingrese un numero entre 0 y 7.");
            }
        }
        suma = suma + nota;
    }
    prom= suma /notas;
    System.out.println("promedio de las notas:"+prom );
```

La falla consiste en que el programa no valida que la nota ingresada esté dentro del rango permitido (de 0 a 7). Para corregir esto, podemos modificar el código para que la validación se haga dentro de un bucle while: